# How to pronounce the word агнцев (three consonants in row)?

Tags: произношение, согласные

In Второзаконие 32:13-14 I read the word агнец, which appears in genitive plural.

> Он вознес его на высоту земли и кормил произведениями полей, и питал его медом из камня и елеем из твердой скалы, маслом коровьим и молоком овечьим, и туком **агнцев** и овнов Васанских и козлов, и тучною пшеницею, и ты пил вино, кровь виноградных ягод.

**How to pronounce this word (агнцев)?**

There are three consonants in a row (гнц). Isn't there any vowel sound in between these, especially in between the г and the н?

Answer (score 4):

You can hear my pronunciation here (I'm a native speaker):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9c5ff-vyZgcTi00c2VMUC00VWc/view

Comment: clear and articulate

Answer (score 3):

You pronounce a schwa between *г* and *н*: *['agənt͡sɨf]*.

However, if the poetic rhythm calls for a two-syllable word, like here:

> С тобой люблю я, в мыслях сладких,
>   Собрать, устроить, просветить
>   Народы; тигров, к крови падких,
>   В смиренных агнцев превратить.

, the *г* itself becomes lenient (vowel-like) and articulates as a nasalized uvular stop: *['aɢ̃nt͡sɨf]*

Comment: I fail to make it two syllables. It's always somewhat like ['a-gən-t͡sɨf] when I try to pronounce it.

Comment: @embert: you have to use an uvular, not velar, stop for *г*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_stop , but if you fail to articulate it, a good approximation would be just making the leading *а* nasalized and omitting the *г* altogether. What is your mother tongue if I may ask?

Comment: Why would it get turned into uvular?

Comment: @jwalker: because your tongue can only move so fast. Both *г* and *ц* are stops, with quite a sonorant nasal in between, so the only way to avoid *гнц* sound as a syllable is lenite the *г* by nasalizing it. This can be only done by shifting the place of articulation lower: you can't pronounce a nasalized velar stop but you can an uvular or deeper one.

Comment: @Quassnoi Sorry, still not sure what you mean. Are you saying that making it uvular helps with articulation? I don't think you can hear an uvular stop in accentless Russian. So could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Quassnoi I hit "comment" and then saw your edit. Well, I also don't agree you really have to make _г_ nasal. Fricative maybe, but not nasal. And why would velar nasal be a problem? If it were _ангец_, you'd get exactly that in relaxed speech all the time.

Comment: @jwalker: you could in fact make it fricative as well, that's one way to pronounce it too. As for a nasalized velar, try speaking with an exaggerated French pronunciation, like Mr. Vorobyaninov's mother-in-law in "The 12 chairs". Make all sounds nasalized.  Now, try saying something with a *г* in it, say *огонь*. See where articulation goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33067/discussion-between-jwalker-and-quassnoi).

Comment: @quassnoi Think I got you now. The гн becomes then part of the first syllable and the sound is nasal and similar to the end of *wrong*. Native language is [Kölsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colognian_language) :P

Comment: @embert: can you pronounce *Arntzen* as a two-syllable word? Just replace *r* with *g* and you're there.

Answer (score 0):

The system wants 30 characters lets try again:

Try this one: https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86&lang=ru-en

Answer (score -3):

Slavic languages are notorious for use of consonant clusters. Russian is not that bad when compared to, say, Polish, but still one may have a hard time mastering those.

Like @Quassnoi said, sometimes it may sound as if schwa were in between consonants, but basically you should really try not to pronounce any vowels at all.

Now try to pronounce a funny made-up word *контрвзбзднуть*.

Comment: What a word!...Polish is worse? For me polish sounds like having lots of shsh and it appears to be the slavic version of french

Comment: @embert: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aVCgV6tIjE

Comment: Actually ангнец is a borrowing from Church Slavonic. Russian native word is ягнёнок. Church Slavonic is characterized by неполнограсие (omitting vowels where they would be in Russian).

Comment: @Anixx Does it affect its pronunciation in any way?

Comment: Of course. Compare other words: глава-голова, власть-волость, глас-голос, враг-ворог etc.

Comment: @Anixx They all are pronounced according to their spelling regardless of their origin, aren't they? Or do you say _гэлава_ (э for schwa) even though it's written as _глава_?

Comment: You hadn't answer the question, you've just confirmed that some other answer is OK.

Comment: @shabunc That wasn't my intention though. My point is that clear pronunciation does not require schwas. If they slip through, it's not a standard but rather a relaxed way of speaking. E. g. if you heard extreme _аганцев_, you'd still have no doubt about it. That was basically the meaning of "try" in my answer.

Comment: Also I attempted to answer a broader question of consonant cluster pronunciation, i. e. there are no schwas in _стрелять_, _взгромоздиться_, and even _контрвзбзднуть_.

Comment: @jwalker: not my downvotes, but there definitely is a schwa in *контрвзбзднуть* (or any word starting with *контр+C*): http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C/#ru http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B/#ru http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81/#ru etc)

Comment: @Quassnoi Agree, cross out _контр_ from "pure" examples.